# Refresh page with Submit button in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, submit, refresh

How to refresh page in MVC View when click submit button?

```
<input class="btn_edit" type="submit" name="action" value="Save changes"/>
```

Thanks for answer and any ideas...

Comment: what you actually mean?

Comment: form will be posted and page will automatically reload is'nt it?

Comment: I have this edit form, that I create and I do not redirect it to other pages after press button submit. It is edit form, where you edit your data, and after you press submit it looks like nothing happens, then if you refresh page, then you see changes

Comment: in form post action redirect to this action you are returning View currently from the post action of form?